# Performance of a big layout with many View.GONE views

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout

I've created a very big layout (approx 2000 lines) that contains a large number of views and sub-layouts, often with weighted measures. The tree is pretty complex and goes down to 8 or more levels of nesting.
To create different "perspectives", the app programmatically sets some of the views' visibility to View.GONE, expecially those one that are at the head of a tree of views that I don't want to be displayed, in different moments of the app life cycle, and sometimes changes the weights to resize views; hence, the final layout that is displayed to the user contains at every time not more than 1/3 of the views and view-trees that are in the main layout.

I don't care about the performance at "switch" time, so when the user switches from one perspective to the other, I've got plenty of time to switch on and off the visibility and that's not a problem.

Instead, does having so many view and view trees set to View.GONE affect performance at runtime? What is the effect of GONE views on CPU and Memory performance, in contrast to a smaller layout (maybe programmatically inflated) where all views are displayed?

Comment: it affects performance , specially low specs devices. If you must need to create heavy layout as you said, then use Constraint layout. It is more flexible that relative layout.

Comment: Constraint layout can be a slightly improvement, but I think that the real problem might be the view trees that have their parent set to GONE: how are they treated, like dead objects, or are they still "alive"?

Comment: i think GONE layout still affects. Can't you make different fragments for that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually while creating complex layout have to use constraint layout.

ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

Please find the doc from url :

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Yes, as I said to Divyesh Patel, this is a good suggestion, but the real problem might be the view trees that have their parent set to GONE: how are they treated, like dead objects, or are they still "alive"?

Comment: is it possible to make invisible instead of gone in your requirement ?

Comment: No because the visible views take the place of the gone views. For example, in certain situations there might be 4 views organized in a cross, other times, 6 views organized as horizontal layout

Comment: try with weights for ex : 6 views is layout weight is 6 . if you want to gone do put layout weight is zero. I think it will be helpful

Comment: inside constarint layout have to use with weights. it would be better.